Problems to create a carousel of cards and work with overflow css prop
I have a carousel of cards.
.carousel {
    display: flex;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.cards {
    display: flex;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    justify-content: space-between; /* Ensure cards are spaced */
    width: 100%; /* Use full width for the cards */
}

.card {
    flex: 0 0 30%; /* Ensure the cards have consistent size */
    margin-right: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden; /* Prevent overflow */
}

.card {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin: 0;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    transition: transform 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
    text-decoration: none;
    min-width: calc(100% / 5);
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.card:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.card:active {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    object-fit: cover;
    max-height: 400px;
}

.card .title {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
}

.card .subtitle {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #666;
}

.carousel-controls {
    position: absolute; /* Define os controles como posicionamento absoluto */
    top: 50%; /* Centraliza verticalmente os controles */
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* Ajusta para garantir que o centro esteja alinhado */
    width: 100%; /* Define que os controles ocupam a largura total do carrossel */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; /* Espaça os botões para as extremidades */
}

.carousel-button {
    background: #0077B6;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 0.3s;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute; /* Posiciona os botões dentro do contêiner relativo */
    top: 50%; /* Centraliza verticalmente no contêiner */
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* Ajusta para alinhar exatamente no centro */
}

#prev {
    left: -20px; /* Ajuste à esquerda fora do carrossel */
}

#next {
    right: -20px; /* Ajuste à direita fora do carrossel */
}

<div data-aos="fade-right" class="carousel-outer-wrapper">
  <div data-aos="fade-right" class="carousel">
    <div data-aos="fade-down"class="cards" id="carousel-cards">
      <a href="de-cara-nova.html" class="card">
        <img src="./images/uiux.jpg" alt="Solução 1">
        <div class="title">UI/UX. Ganhe uma cara nova!</div>
        <div class="subtitle">
          <p data-aos="fade-left">Na O.F. Consulting, acreditamos que a experiência do usuário (UX) e o design da interface do usuário (UI) são essenciais para o sucesso de qualquer aplicação. Nossos especialistas em UI/UX desenvolvem soluções intuitivas e eficientes, sempre priorizando a usabilidade e a satisfação do cliente. A nossa abordagem começa com uma compreensão profunda das necessidades do usuário final, permitindo a criação de interfaces que sejam não apenas atraentes visualmente, mas que também facilitem a navegação e maximizem o engajamento. Trabalhamos em estreita colaboração com nossos clientes para garantir que cada detalhe da interface reflita os valores da marca e proporcione uma experiência única e eficiente.</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="web-mobile.html" class="card">
        <img src="./images/webdesktop_wallpaper.png" alt="Solução 2">
        <div class="title">Aplicativos Web e Mobile</div>
        <div class="subtitle">
          <p>Na era digital, a presença online é essencial para qualquer negócio. Nossa equipe de desenvolvimento de aplicativos web e móveis cria soluções robustas e personalizadas, que atendem às necessidades específicas de cada cliente. Seja um aplicativo responsivo ou uma solução móvel nativa, oferecemos uma experiência otimizada para qualquer plataforma. Utilizando as mais recentes tecnologias e metodologias ágeis, desenvolvemos desde aplicações simples até plataformas complexas, garantindo desempenho, segurança e escalabilidade. A O.F. Consulting está preparada para transformar suas ideias em soluções funcionais, entregando produtos que geram valor imediato ao negócio.</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="infra-cloud.html" class="card">
        <img src="./images/cloud-arch.png" alt="Solução 3">
        <div class="title">Infraestrutura e Ambientes Cloud</div>
        <div class="subtitle">
          <p>A infraestrutura tecnológica e a migração para ambientes em nuvem são essenciais para a modernização e o crescimento escalável das empresas. Na O.F. Consulting, oferecemos uma abordagem estratégica para infraestrutura e cloud, garantindo alta disponibilidade, segurança e eficiência em ambientes flexíveis e escaláveis. Implementamos soluções que reduzem custos operacionais, aumentam a produtividade e asseguram o desempenho ideal dos sistemas. Nossos especialistas em cloud computing estão prontos para planejar, implementar e gerenciar ambientes em nuvem que permitem às empresas se adaptar rapidamente às mudanças do mercado e às demandas crescentes.</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="solucoes-arquitetura.html" class="card">
        <img src="./images/arch.png" alt="Solução 4">
        <div class="title">Arquitetura de Soluções</div>
        <div class="subtitle">
          <p>Desenvolver uma solução eficaz requer uma arquitetura sólida. A O.F. Consulting se especializa em projetar e implementar arquiteturas de soluções que garantem flexibilidade, escalabilidade e segurança. Trabalhamos lado a lado com nossos clientes para entender seus desafios e identificar a melhor estrutura tecnológica para atender às suas necessidades. Nossos arquitetos de soluções utilizam padrões modernos de arquitetura, como microsserviços e arquitetura orientada a eventos, para criar sistemas robustos e fáceis de manter, alinhando as necessidades de curto prazo com a estratégia de longo prazo do cliente.</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="consultoria.html" class="card">
        <img src="./images/consulting_wallpaper.png" alt="Solução 5">
        <div class="title">Consultoria para Impulsionar seu Negócio</div>
        <div class="subtitle">
          <p>Na O.F. Consulting, nossa missão é apoiar o crescimento de nossos clientes por meio de uma consultoria estratégica e focada em resultados. Oferecemos insights valiosos que ajudam empresas a superar desafios e aproveitar oportunidades em um mercado dinâmico. Com uma abordagem personalizada, trabalhamos de forma colaborativa para entender seus objetivos de negócios e recomendar soluções que aumentam a eficiência, reduzem custos e melhoram a competitividade. Seja no planejamento estratégico, na transformação digital ou na otimização de processos, nossa consultoria está preparada para impulsionar o seu negócio a novos patamares.</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="carousel-button" id="prev">
    <span class="material-icons">arrow_back</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-button" id="next">
    <span class="material-icons">arrow_forward</span>
  </button>
</div>

Carousel has next and prev buttons to navigate between cards. Carousel overflow is visible, because i wanna to be able to see unfocused cards

But when overflow is set to visible, buttons next and prev stops to work. At responsive mode (mobile) the buttons worked because overflow changes to hidden.
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .carousel {
        width: 100vw;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }

JS:
function updateCarousel(direction) {
    const cardWidth = cardsContainer.children[0].offsetWidth; // Largura do card
    const scrollMargin = parseInt(getComputedStyle(cardsContainer.children[0]).marginRight) || 0;
    const scrollWidth = cardWidth + scrollMargin; // Largura total do card com margens

    const scrollStep = direction === 'next' ? scrollWidth : -scrollWidth;

    // Use scrollBy instead of manipulating scrollLeft directly to preserve overflow visible behavior
    cardsContainer.scrollBy({
        left: scrollStep,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
}


// Adiciona eventos aos botões de navegação
nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('nextClick');
    updateCarousel('next');
});

prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('prevClick');
    updateCarousel('prev');
});

// Intervalo automático para troca de cards
setInterval(() => {
    if (currentIndex < totalCards - 1) {
        currentIndex++;
    } else {
        currentIndex = 0; // Volta para o primeiro
    }
    updateCarousel();
}, 10000);

How to solve this problem?

Issue is with overflow: auto as it hides the "buttons" or cut them as they are overflowing from container which you already know. Now to fix this issue will create a additional container above first fade-right div.
In my case I have added card-outter div which has below css properties :
.card-outter {
    padding: 0 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
 }

padding: 0 50px will create a gap between "card-outter" and "card-inner" (which is basically your "fade-right" class) due to which overflowing buttons gets room to display and they does not gets cutout. You can use dev tools to visually understand what I have achieved and below is working example of it.


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mainDiv {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card-outter {
  padding: 0 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card-inner {
  position: relative;
}

.actual-card {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vw;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.prev-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  top: 25vw
}

.next-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 25vw
}
<h2 class="mainDiv">
  <div class="card-outter">
    <div class="card-inner">
      <div class="actual-card">CleanCodeEditor</div>
      <button class="prev-btn">Previous</button>
      <button class="next-btn">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</h2>



